# Connect-azureAD powershell in azure function

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-function-app

I need to connect to AD in azure function app using powershell script. (as it is in function i need to do it without prompt)
I am trying this:

```
# Import AzureAD 
Import-Module "D:\home\site\modules\AzureAD.psd1" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$appId = "myAppId"
$thumb = "certThumb"
$tenantId = "myTenantId"
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $tenantId -ApplicationId  $appId -CertificateThumbprint $thumb
```

Unfortunately i am getting following error:

```
The term 'Connect-AzureAD' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

I copied azureAd modules to fs of the function app, but it still looks like importing it doesn't give any result.

Do you know a way to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the AzureAD module in Azure Functions requires a workaround now: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-powershell-worker/issues/232#issuecomment-536744760

This will probably be fixed soon.

By the way, instead of copying the module into your app, consider using the [Managed Dependencies feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell#dependency-management)

Comment: At the moment the way with managed dependencies feature doesn't work. First way works - Thanks Anatoli!

Comment: @bryniek What I meant was that Managed Dependencies will take care of delivering the module files to the file system, without the need to manually include the module into your app. This seems to be working as designed even for the AzureAD module. But locating and spawning the 64-bit powershell.exe is still required.