# Connect-AzureAD PowerShell in Azure Function fails

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

Not related to [Connect-azureAD powershell in azure function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58189800/connect-azuread-powershell-in-azure-function)

I have a simple Azure function (HTTP trigger) written in PowerShell.

```
$user = 'user@domain.com';
$pass = 'password';

Import-Module AzureAD -UseWindowsPowerShell;
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force;
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($Username, $secpasswd);

Connect-AzureAD -Credential $cred;
Disconnect-AzureAD;
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession;
```

The first time it runs, it works. If I hit it again, it throws an exception "Exception calling "GetSteppablePipeline" with "1" argument(s): "The parameter is incorrect." If I  call it again after an hour, it works again (1 time), then it fails again with the same error.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested in my environment.

Please use the below code :

```
$user = 'user@domain.com';
$secpasswd = 'password' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force;

Import-Module AzureAD -UseWindowsPowerShell;
$cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($user, $secpasswd);

Connect-AzureAD -Credential $cred;
Disconnect-AzureAD;
```

Comment: It was the Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession line that was causing this. Your answer led me in the right direction. Thank you!